# Can I substitute bread flour for bread machine flour?

Tags: substitutions, bread, flour

Can I use Bread Flour instead of Bread Machine Flour when making a loaf of wheat bread?  Recipe calls for 1 and 1/2 cups of wheat flour and 4 cups of bread machine flour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Bread machine flour" and "bread flour" are interchangeable terms.

> Bread flour, sometimes called bread machine flour, is what most bread maker recipe books will say to use in order to achieve the best results. ([Source](https://makebreadathome.com/whats-the-best-flour-for-your-bread-maker/))

So yes, you should use bread flour in the recipe. It has higher protein than all-purpose flour and will help your bread rise better and hold its shape.